# Vue-i18next: maintain different languages for different country

Tags: vue.js, i18next

I am working on a Vue-based application where I have to maintain different translations on the same set of languages for different countries.
i.e

US:

- ES
- EN

SPAIN

- ES
- EN

...

The whole application functionality is same and theres no specific codebase changes based on different countries required. Its just that the translation texts are different for different countries.
eg:- The title is different for english language for US and Spain.

Has anyone done similiar with i18next plugin?

Comment: "attranslate" is a new tool that is specifically designed for a semi-automated "synchronization" of translation-files: https://github.com/fkirc/attranslate In order to efficiently maintain region-specific differences for the same base-language, you can use attranslate with the sync-without-translate-mode.

Answer (score 0):

[Locale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale_(computer_software)) can be defined as, `en-UK` which is what you are looking for, `English` in UK.

So in order to make a support for this, you need to create files with `lang-Region` for each combination, and then use it as the `language` prop.